# $\frac{4}{5^{x+1}}-\frac{1}{5^x} = -0.04$

Tags: exponential-function

$$\frac{4}{5^{x+1}}-\frac{1}{5^x} = -0.04$$

This equality seems too simple to solve but I've to know what to do.

The first thing I thought is $\frac{1}{5^x} = 5^{-x}$.

However, no idea about others.

Instead of solving this question, I'd like to get your tips/hints for the terms like $-0.04$ (which are making me very very confused).

Comment: Recognize that -0,04 is $-\frac{1}{25} = -\frac{1}{5^2}$

Comment: @Malcolm Why is it equal to $-\frac{1}{25}$?

Comment: $-0,04 = -\frac{4}{100} = -\frac{4}{4\cdot 25}$

Answer (score 1):

write $$\frac{4}{5\cdot 5^x}-\frac{1}{5^x}=-\frac{4}{100}$$ and Substitute $$5^x=t$$
or $$\frac{4}{5\cdot 5^x}-\frac{5}{5\cdot 5^x}=-\frac{4}{100}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac4{5^{x+1}}-\dfrac1{5^x}=\dfrac{4-5}{5^{x+1}}$$

Now, $0.04=\dfrac4{100}=?$

Comment: I still didn't get it.

Comment: @Busi, Where is ur confusion?

Comment: At the first step you've done.

Comment: @Busi, $\dfrac ab-\dfrac cd=?$

Comment: We're finding a common denominator here.  $$\frac 4{5^{x+1}} - \frac 1{5^x} = \frac {4}{5^{x+1}} - \frac 5{5\cdot 5^x} = \frac{4}{5^{x+1}}-\frac 5{5^{x+1}} = \cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(4-5\right)\frac{1}{5^{x+1}}=-0.04$$

$$-\frac{1}{5^{x+1}}=-\frac{1}{25}$$

$$x+1=2$$

$$x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\begin{align}\frac{4}{5^{x+1}}-\frac{1}{5^x} = -0.04&\implies5^{x+1}\left(\frac{4}{5^{x+1}}-\frac{1}{5^x}\right)=4-5=-0.04\cdot5^{x+1}\\&\implies5^{x+1}=\frac1{0.04}=25=5^2\\&\implies x+1=2\\&\implies x=1\end{align}$$

---

Check:

$$\frac4{5^{1+1}}-\frac1{5^1}=\frac4{25}-\frac5{25}=-\frac1{25}=-0.04$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $5^{x+1}$ and you get:

$$\dfrac{4\cdot 5^{x+1}}{5^{x+1}}-\dfrac{1\cdot 5^{x+1}}{5^{x}}=-0.04 \cdot 5^{x+1}$$ 
$$4-5=-0.04 \cdot 5^{x+1}$$ 
$$\implies 25=5^{x+1}$$
$$\implies x=1$$

Comment: How did you get $4-5=-0.04 \cdot 5^{x+1}$?

Comment: multiplied both sides by $5^{x+1}$, the terms cancel

Comment: Can you show that?

Comment: updated the solution

Comment: Now why isn't it $-\frac{1.5^{x+1}}{5^x}$?

Comment: because i made a mistake :) nice catch. updated again

Comment: Oh, got it perfectly! However, the last thing I didn't get is $4-5=-0.04 \cdot 5^{x+1}$ If you can explain this one too, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Busi Note that $5^{x+1}=5\cdot 5^x$